# Accessing a function of a objects class as an array of pointers of another class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, inheritance

y'all I'm having an issue trying to access the member functions of an object that I have stored in an array of pointers full of objects.

Header:

```
#ifndef COURSEGRADES__H
#define COURSEGRADES__H
#include "Essay.h"
#include "FinalExam.h"
#include "PassFailExam.h"
#include "GradedActivity.h"

class CourseGrades:public Essay, public FinalExam, public PassFailExam, public GradedActivity
{
    public:
        CourseGrades();
        void setLab(GradedActivity &l);
        void setPassFailExam(PassFailExam &pf);
        void setEssay(Essay &e);
        void setPassFailFinal(FinalExam &fe);
        void print();
    private:
        GradedActivity *grades[4];
};

#endif // COURSEGRADES_H
```

CPP

```
#include "CourseGrades.h"
#include <iostream>
CourseGrades::CourseGrades()
{
    //ctor
}
void CourseGrades::setLab(GradedActivity &l)
{
    grades[0] = &l;
}
void CourseGrades::setPassFailExam(PassFailExam &pf)
{
    grades[1] =  &pf;
}
void CourseGrades::setEssay(Essay &e)
{
    grades[2] = &e;
}
void CourseGrades::setPassFailFinal(FinalExam &fe)
{
    grades[3] = &fe;

}
void CourseGrades::print()
{
    std::cout << grades[0]->getScore() << "\t" << grades[0]->getLetterGrade() << std::endl;
    std::cout << grades[1]->getScore() << "\t" << grades[1]->getLetterGrade() << std::endl;
    std::cout << grades[2]->getScore //this function exists in the Essay class but I can't access it from here.
}
```

So I'm trying to access the third object in the grade array which is an object of the essay class which includes a unique function that is separate from the get score function in the GradeActivity class. I'll also need to access its unique getLetterGrade method but once I get one I should be able to find out how to get the other. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please try to make this a [mcve]. Using raw arrays and raw pointers like this should be avoided. Have a look at `std::array<GradedActivity, 4>`, or maybe `std::array<std::unique_ptr<GradedActivity>, 4>` is most likely a better choice.

Comment: std::cout << grades[1]->getScore() << "\t" << grades[1]->getLetterGrade() << std::endl; // Prints 0 for the Score and F for the LetterGrade since the score and grade for the essay are calucalted differently than the other three and I'm unable to access the getScore and getLetterGrade functions in the essay class.

Comment: Please take the time to read the link i posted, and try to edit this question accordingly. It will increase your chances of anyone being able to help you greatly.